# What could Error in this java program to compute sine?

Tags: java

I have written this code to compute the sine of an angle. This works fine for smaller angles, say upto +-360. But with larger angles it starts giving faulty results. (When I say larger, I mean something like within the range +-720 or +-1080)

In order to get more accurate results I increased the number of times my loop runs. That gave me better results but still that too had its limitations.

So I was wondering if there is any fault in my logic or do I need to fiddle with the conditional part of my loop? How can I overcome this shortcoming of my code? The inbuilt java sine function gives correct results for all the angles I have tested..so where am I going wrong?

Also can anyone give me an idea as to how do I modify the condition of my loop so that it runs until I get a desired decimal precision?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


class SineFunctionManual 
{
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the angle for which you want to compute sine : ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int degreeAngle = input.nextInt();  //Angle in degree.
        input.close();

        double radianAngle = Math.toRadians(degreeAngle);   //Sine computation is done in terms of radian angle
        System.out.println(radianAngle);
        double sineOfAngle = radianAngle,prevVal = radianAngle; //SineofAngle contains actual result, prevVal contains the next term to be added
        //double fractionalPart = 0.1;  // This variable is used to check the answer to a certain number of decimal  places, as seen in the for loop

        for(int i=3;i<=20;i+=2)
        {
            prevVal = (-prevVal)*((radianAngle*radianAngle)/(i*(i-1)));     //x^3/3! can be written as ((x^2)/(3*2))*((x^1)/1!), similarly x^5/5! can be written as ((x^2)/(5*4))*((x^3)/3!) and so on. The negative sign is added because each successive term has alternate sign.
            sineOfAngle+=prevVal;

            //int iPart = (int)sineOfAngle;
            //fractionalPart = sineOfAngle - iPart; //Extracting the fractional part to check the number of decimal places.
        }

        System.out.println("The value of sin of "+degreeAngle+" is : "+sineOfAngle);

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean with large angles?

Comment: Can you draw me an angle of more than 360 degrees, as I always think it looks like it is less than 360 degrees.

Comment: @elune - I mean in the range +-720 or +-1080

Comment: @PeterLawrey -  Practically it might not be possible but theoretically there is a thing called sin 1080 right? Even if I use the Java inbuilt sin function it gives me proper results for angles like +-1080. So it must be possible to correct my code so as to evaluate the sine of such angles properly too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polynomial approximation for sine diverges widely for large positive and large negative values. Remember, since varies from -1 to 1 over *all real numbers*. Polynomials, on the other hand, particularly ones with higher orders, can't do that.

I would recommend using the periodicity of sine to your advantage.

```
int degreeAngle = input.nextInt() % 360;
```

This will give accurate answers, even for very, very large angles, without requiring an absurd number of terms.

Comment: If the integer entered is going to be positive, then an even better value to use for `degreeAngle` would be `(input.nextInt() + 180) % 360 - 180`

Comment: And an even better way would reduce the range to -90 to 90 degrees, with the sign of the answer possibly being flipped. In other words, the close to 0, the better.

Answer (score 1):

The further you get from `x=0`, the more terms you need, of the Taylor expansion for `sin x`, to get within a particular accuracy of the correct answer.  You're stopping around the 20th term, which is fine for small angles.  If you want better accuracy for large angles, you'll just need to add more terms.